# Debugging JavaScript in IE11

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-11

The F12 tools look good, and I see controls for most of what I would like to use (Continue, Step In, Step Out). But the HTML app I want to debug runs before I can start the F12 tools. What I need is a Restart button, it would seem to me.

Am I missing seeing this, or am I out of luck?

By the way, I see the same problem in Chrome.

Comment: Just refresh the browser after pressing f12, ctrl-f5 to do a full refresh.

Comment: put it in debug mode and press crtl-r (will refresh it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open your Page.
2. Press `F12` to display the tools.
3. Switch to the debugging tab.
4. Add your breakpoints.
5. Refresh by pressing `F5` or `Ctrl+F5` or`Ctrl+R`.

Comment: This works but intermittently. First time, only Ctrl + R worked. All failed after that for three or four reloads, but eventually it "stuck" on the breakpoint, and I can do what I want.

Comment: My IE11 does the debug wonderful after reloading the page by pressing only `F5`. Maybe you just found the first errors in your code.;-) Try out: 
`window.onload = function(){
//Debug at this point
console.log("test");
}`

Comment: i used to clear network cache just in case as well; 
also sometimes my app won't load until i close F12 -> then it works -> i press F12 again and work as usual